# How to use Xindy with TeXShop/LaTeX Mac OS X (error: sort åäö in index)

Tags: indexing, texshop, xindy

I am new to LaTeX since a year (old man trying...) and have some problem with index. I write in Swedish and the letters "å ä ö" are sorted wrongly in the index. (äåöabc...) Otherwise the indexing works well with MakeIndex.

I have tried with Xindy but something goes wrong. "Åäö" works well in text! 
How do I use Xindy? ( `\usepackage{texindy}` ? Anything more to add (TeXShop/LaTeX)? Please help!

This is part of my preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\usepackage{makeidx}
\newcommand{\boldidx}[1]{{\bf #1}}

....
This kind of index in text:

\index{Säker plats|boldidx}Säker plats 

....
```

Is TeXShop OK to use? Is there a better one for Mac OS X Mavericks?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 4):

`texindy` is the minimalistic form of `xindy`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
This kind of index in text:

\index{Säker plats|textbf}Säker plats \index{Säker platsXX@\textbf{Säker plats}}

foo\index{Åäö}\index{Aäö}
bar\index{äö}\index{aø}\index{ohne}\index{øæ}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

run it with

```
pdflatex <file>
texindy <file.idx>
pdflatex <file>
pdflatex <file>
```

and you'll get:

[image]

With `xindy` you can define your own module. See documentation. An alternative sorting is possible with:

```
 texindy -L swedish -M utf8 test7.idx
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a default module that sorts å/ä/ö under their own headings at the end of the index, as expected in a swedish index?

Comment: Hi. How do I Run texindy within Texshop? Can´t find it.. Also, I did mean this sort order: (Ärla, Adam, Bertil, Östen, Osten, Åre, Årtal) should be: (Adam, Bertil, Osten, Åre, Ärla, Östen). Did I explain that..:? o I have to run texindy manual; it´s not in the list in Texshop!

Comment: @user43352: in the configuration menu of TeXshop where you define the index program you must replace `makeindex` by the above commnad. As an alternative you can run the command in a terminal. However, I do not understand what you mean by sorting: - ???

Comment: In Swedish we have alphabetic order abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyzåäö but MAKEINDEX is sorting in this order åäöabcdefghijklmnoprtstuvxyz which means that "å" is sorting before "a" instead of after "z"...

Comment: @user43352: the sorting order is defined in the xindy module for swedish which can easily be adopted. However, see my edited answer where the second example has the latter sorting.